# Подключение стиля контрола из другой сборки (xaml)

Tags: xaml

У меня есть стиль кнопки  с присоединённым свойством Image, который определён в отдельной сборке:

```
 <Style 
    x:Key="ExSimpleButton"
    TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border 
                    x:Name="Head"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    BorderBrush="Transparent"
                    BorderThickness="1">
                    <Grid>
                        <Image
                            x:Name="ButtonImage"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Source="{Binding Path=(classes:AttachedImage.Image),RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Head" Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF525252"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseDirectlyOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Head" Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="1"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Есть класс, определяющий свойство Image:

```
namespace ExCtrl.Classes
```

{
    public class AttachedImage
    {
        #region Описание свойства
        public static DependencyProperty ImageProperty;

```
    public static ImageSource GetImage(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ImageSource)obj.GetValue(ImageProperty);
    }
    public static void SetImage(DependencyObject obj, ImageSource value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ImageProperty, value);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Конструктор
    public AttachedImage()
    {
        var metadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((ImageSource)null);
        ImageProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Image", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(AttachedImage), metadata);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

В xaml главного окна приложения определено пространство имён из этой сборки:

```
 xmlns:ExClasses="clr-namespace:ExCtrlClasses;assembly=ExCtrl"
```

При попытке задать значение свойства Image:

```
 <Button
                        x:Name="btnSysMenu"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Style="{DynamicResource ExSimpleButton}"
                        ExClasses:AttachedImage.Image="{StaticResource WinLogo}"/>
```

Выплывает ошибка: "Значение не может быть неопределённым..."

Вопрос: Что-бы это значило? И чего я делаю не так?
Уже всю голову сломал!!!
Помогите, кто может!!!

Comment: Попробуйте поиграться с `StaticResource` `DynamicResource`, или `ExClasses:ExSimpleButton`

Comment: Блин! Ну никаких изменений!!!

Comment: А namespace точно правильный? Приведите пример с шапкой того контроле. И xaml контроле полностью. А так: `ExClasses:AttachedImage.ExSimpleButton` , это предположение..

Answer (score 0):

Словарь ресурсов:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
x:Name="Styles"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExCtrl.Resources"
xmlns:classes="clr-namespace:ExCtrl.Classes">
<Style 
    x:Key="ExSimpleButton"
    TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border 
                    x:Name="Head"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    BorderBrush="Transparent"
                    BorderThickness="1">
                    <Grid>
                        <Image
                            x:Name="ButtonImage"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Source="{Binding Path=(classes:AttachedImage.Image),RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Head" Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF525252"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseDirectlyOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Head" Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="1"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Файл AttachedImage.cs:

```
using System.Windows;
```

using System.Windows.Media;

namespace ExCtrl.Classes
{
    public class AttachedImage
    {
        #region Описание свойства
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty;

```
    public static ImageSource GetImage(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ImageSource)obj.GetValue(ImageProperty);
    }
    public static void SetImage(DependencyObject obj, ImageSource value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ImageProperty, value);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Конструктор
    static AttachedImage()
    {
        var metadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((ImageSource)null);
        ImageProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Image", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(AttachedImage), metadata);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

Шапка xaml главного окна:`

```
 x:Name="mainWindow" 
x:Class="Em.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Em"
xmlns:ExClasses="clr-namespace:ExCtrl.Classes;assembly=ExCtrl"
mc:Ignorable="d"
```